# Should an interpolation coincide the original function on the given data points?

Tags: terminology, interpolation

Suppose having a model $f(x)=y$ where $f$ is unkown. Moreover, suppose you  have some data points for this model i.e. $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), \dots , (x_n,y_n)$. 
If one can find an approximate of $f $ called $\tilde{f}$ using the given data points.

When such aproximation is called interpolation? should the approximation vanish on the given data points in order to be considered as an interpolation ( i.e. $\tilde{f}(x_i)=y_i$ for all $i$) ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: As Ross Millikan said, there is a difference in terms. If you want to match the data exactly, it is called *interpolation*, if not -- *approximation*

Comment: I will add this comment for users checking the same question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65532/interpolation-extrapolation-and-approximations-rigorously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an interpolating function should pass exactly through all the data points.  You need enough adjustable parameters to make this happen.  It can also be useful to find an approximating function that has fewer parameters and does not pass exactly through the points.  If there is noise in your data, some forms of interpolating function, like a high degree polynomial, will wiggle a lot between the points.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but would you please add a reference to support your answer as  "Yes".  I mean  on what  did you base your answer? Is there a clear definition ?

Comment: If you look at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) it shows various interpolation techniques, all of which produce  functions that go exactly through the points.